# Angular 7 Performance Impact with Dynamic Styles

Tags: angular, ng-style

I am creating a component which utilises a large number of dynamic styles (eg 10) [styles.xx] so the user can customise the component's appearance. In addition the component may be repeated in the parent component quite a few times (eg 10-20 times). Examples of styles include:

```
[style.color]
[style.font-size]
[style.text-alignment]
```

I've incorporated `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`  to minimise the impact on performance.

This may sound highly subjective I do notice when I scroll with the styles incorporated vs no styles, it is slightly sluggish in the scroll performance.

My questions are:

1. By utilising a large number of  dynamic styles in a repeated component can this impact performance? Even with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?
2. Using `ngStyles` vs Styles improve performance?
3. What other strategies can I use to minimise performance impact?

NOTE: I only need the styles on init of the component.

I'm toying with using `document.getElementsByClassName` and the set attribute to change the styles on init, but hoping for an easier way utilising the styles.

Thanks in advance

Example of Part of component ( I am using Ionic).

```
<ion-card *ngIf="traits.isLock && isRead !== 4 && element.is_card_read" fxFlex fxLayout="horizontal" class="element-inactive element" [style.background-color]="element.card_read_bg_color" style="min-height: 50px" no-margin>   
    <div fxFlex>  

      <div fxFlex fxLayout="vertical">   
        <div style="width:100%" [style.text-align]="labelAlignment">
          <label *ngIf="element.is_label_show" class="label caption"  [style.color]="element.read_caption_color" [style.font-size.px]="labelSize">{{columnName}}</label>
        </div>      
        <div style="width:100%" [style.text-align]="textAlignment">
          <span [style.font-size.px]="textSize" [style.color]="element.read_text_color">{{value}}</span>
        </div>      
      </div>    
    </div> 
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: Right off the bat I would recommend building an object of the styles and use `ngStyle`.  I wouldn't use `document` querying.  It would help to see what you have currently.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I've updated with sample code. I have an ngIf to show different styles where the above example is where I notice sluggish performance. Also I only need the styles on init if that helps.

Comment: Further to above I end up using scss varibales in my classes which I set on init.